# Shell command to extract string within bracket (String) in a variable like status(running)

Tags: string, bash, shell, command, extract

I am building a AIX bash shell utility whereby i get a dynamic variable with value like status(running).
I just need the string within brakets that is running.
Right now i am able to get the whole word with status along with the brackets using awk print.

Can anyone suggest me how to just extract the running out of it.  Thanks.

Comment: have you looked at the section of the bash man page on `Parameter Expansion`? It has lots of operators that can extract pieces out of a variable based on patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say:

```
s='(running)'
```

Using pure BASH:

```
echo "${s//[()]/}"
running
```

Using sed:

```
echo "$s" | sed 's/[()]//g'
running
```

Using tr:

```
tr -d '()' <<< "$s"
running
```

**UPDATE:** As per comments by OP:

```
s='status(running)'
```

**Using sed:**

```
echo "$s" | sed 's/^.*(\(.*\)).*$/\1/g'
running
```

**Using pure BASH:**

```
t="${s#*\(}"
echo "${t%)*}"
running
```

Comment: In the example the variable s has been taken as just (running).  But in my scenario the variable value will be status(running).  Will the above command will work by extracting just running out of it?  I dont have access to my AIX machine right now.. so pls clarify.  Thanks Anubahva

Comment: Thanks Anubhava.   I will test this out tomorrow and will update.  thx for your time.

Comment: ok sure, leave a comment here in case you run into any problems.

Comment: Anubhava.. thanks much for your help.. it worked..

Comment: Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.